# Method not getting called in iOS

Tags: ios, methods

I have the following snippet and a call to the method is not working!

```
  @interface myVM(){

        NSArray *results;

   }


 @property (nonatomic, strong) MyModel *model;


 @end

  @implementation myVM


 - (instancetype)initWithItems{

      self = [super init];
      if (!self) return nil;

     **[self.model loadInfo];**

    _DeviceNameArray = self.model.DeviceNames;


 }
```

What is the reason for the method being not called?

Comment: Which method? If you mean `-initWithItems` than put it into interface also.

Comment: Check NSLog(@"%@", self.model )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self.model is not initialized. If you debug it, you will see it is nil.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate and initialize it first:

```
- (instancetype)initWithItems{

      self = [super init];
      if (!self) return nil;

      self.model = [MyModel new];   // like this
      [self.model loadInfo];

    _DeviceNameArray = self.model.DeviceNames;
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time you are calling `[self.model loadInfo];`, the `model` property has not been set yet and is `nil`. You probably want something like:

```
- (instancetype)initWithModel:(MyModel *)aModel {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    self.model = aModel;
    [self.model loadInfo];

    _DeviceNameArray = self.model.DeviceNames;

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should structure your custom init methods like this for better readability.

```
- (instancetype)initWithItems
{
     self = [super init];

     if (self) {

         [self.model loadInfo];
        _DeviceNameArray = self.model.DeviceNames;

     }

     return self;
}
```

The problem is that `self.model` has not been initialised anywhere. It is just a property that contains no information - it is `nil`. You need to assign something to it somewhere.

E.g., pass a model object as parameter like so, `initWithItem:(MyModel *)model`, then assign it to self.model.